# Laravel/Elixir watch doesn't trigger copy

Tags: javascript, laravel, laravel-elixir

My `gulpfile.js` looks as below. If I execute `gulp watch`, the copy task does not get executed on change of `app.js`. In fact, if I have the copy task alone, `gulp watch` will execute copy once and then exit. What am I doing wrong?

```
elixir(function (mix) {
    mix.scripts(
        [
            '../../../bower_components/angular/angular.js'
        ]
    ).copy('resources/assets/js/app.js', 'public/js/app.js')
});
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In order for Elixir to watch all the files inside the `assets` folder you need to instruct it where to look for additional resources. For that you simply need to use the `registerWatcher` method.

Unfortunately Laravel documentation leaves a lot to desire so this option is often overlooked because it's not properly documented.

```
elixir.config.registerWatcher("default", "resources/assets/**", null);

elixir(function (mix) {
    mix.scripts(
        [
            '../../../bower_components/angular/angular.js'
        ]
    ).copy('resources/assets/js/app.js', 'public/js/app.js')
});
```

Comment: For anyone trying this solution with never Laravel versions, make sure to check [the newer Elixir syntax in the docs](https://laravel.com/docs/5.2/elixir), as the above might not always work anymore.